# Non Resident Alien with a W2 and a 1099B - What are the obligations here?

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, 1099-b

I worked in the United States between the 1st of January 2023 and April 15th 2023. In addition to salary I had some RSUs and my company would sell some of the RSUs to cover tax obligations. The broker that kept the RSUs didn't allow me to file a W8BEN so they have a W9 on file which led to me getting a 1099B.

As far as I understand that sale of stock is still not effectively connected & as I have stayed in the US less than < 183 days the capital gains(loss in this case) is exempt from the United States even if I had a tax home in the United States between the 1st of January 2023 and April 15th 2023.

What does one do when they have a 1099B that they shouldn't have as the broker had W9 on file instead of a W8BEN?

Comment: Why did you file W9? What does it mean "didn't allow me to file a W8BEN"? That's not really up to them what your status is.

Comment: This was ShareWorks Solium for RSUs. Company/Morgan Stanley had some policy that didn't allow the platform to have a W8BEN on file for someone present in the States. In addition to RSUs I was getting Options and I think they wanted to track my time spent in America for the options. After leaving I tried changing it but to no luck.

Comment: You should not have reported w9. Plain and simple. Whatever policy they have means nothing to your status. Regardless, file your tax return and report everything correctly and if IRS comes asking questions refer them to that policy.

Comment: Can you tell what "Correctly" means here? Would this go in the schedule NEC?

Comment: How many days were you present in the US in 2021 and 2022, respectively?

Comment: When the RSU vests, you are supposed to receive stock. You are taxed on the value of the stock you received as regular income, in the same way your wages are taxed, at the time you receive the stock. You may then sell the stock, and the "capital gains" is the difference in price between the two. If the company "sold" it immediately upon the RSU vesting, then there is 0 capital gains for those shares, since the price when you got it and sold it are the same. Are you talking about the other shares that you sold later?

Comment: I was in the US for 33 days in 2021 and 83 days in 2021. 

I didn’t sell any of my shares. There was a price delta in the moment I got the shares and at the instant that the tried to sell. It was a small delta and on net I have a $100 capital loss.

Comment: @ggy: Why do you think you "got the shares"? Shares are only taxable when you "actually or constructively received" it, meaning you had control over its disposition. If you had no control over what to do with the shares, then I say you never received them, and they were never taxable before they were sold, so you should only be taxed on the money received from the sale, as wages, with no capital gains (or losses).